# CENTOS 6 - How to install php-mysql when php-common @remi is present?

Tags: php, mysql, centos-6, lamp

I am having troubles adding mysql support for my php installation, this installation was made using a ready to use-package that came with our VPS.

This is my php.info: http://snake.quetzalcoatech.com/info.php

I am trying to install php mysql using:

> yum install php-mysql

And get this output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * extras: mirror.fdcservers.net
 * updates: bay.uchicago.edu
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-14.el6_3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3 for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
           Installed: php-common-5.3.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common = 5.3.17-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64 (base)
               php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.8
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am a noob using Linux, so could you tell me which command should I use to install a compatible php-mysql module?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing all remi php packages, disable remi repository and install the default centos 6 php 5.3.3 packages.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was due to that repo. I had to do a 'yum clean all'. Thanks!